# 2 tableViews in 1 view Controller - error keeps changing

Tags: ios, swift

I have two tableviews in one view controller. when group 1 buttons are clicked they are added to tableview 1, when group 2 buttons are clicked they are supposed to be added to tableview 2. but no matter what I change I get one of these 3 errors:

1. "invalid update"
2. "attempt to insert row 0 into section 0,
3. "unable to dequeue a cell with identifier"

Code:

```
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView:  UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView2: UITableView!
    
    
    var pizzas = [String]()
    var drinks = [String]()
    
    
    
    @IBAction func onAddTapped(sender:UIButton) {
        
        pizzaCount = pizzaCount + 1
        pizzaCounter.text = ("Antal pizza: ") + "\(pizzaCount)"
        
        func add(_ pizza: String) {
            pizzas.append(pizza)
            tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: pizzas.count - 1, section: 0)], with: .fade)
        }
        add(sender.title(for: .normal)!)
        
    }
    @IBAction func onAddTappedDrinks(sender:UIButton) {
        
        func add(_ drink: String) {
            drinks.append(drink)
            tableView2.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: drinks.count - 1, section: 0)], with: .fade)
        }
        add(sender.title(for: .normal)!)
        
    }[![enter image description here][1]][1]
}


extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        
        
        return pizzas.count
        
    }
    
    func tableView2(_ tableView2: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    
    
        return drinks.count
        
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        return tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "item", for: indexPath)
        
    }
    
    
    
    func tableView2(_ tableView2: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath2: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        return self.tableView2.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "item2", for: indexPath2)
        
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        guard let cell = cell as? itemTableViewCell else
        { return }
        
        let pizza = pizzas[indexPath.row]
        cell.titleLabel.text = pizza
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = ("hu")
    }
    
    func tableView2(_ tableView2: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath2: IndexPath) {
        guard let cell = cell as? item2TableViewCell else { return }
        
        let drink = drinks[indexPath2.row]
        cell.titleLabel.text = drink
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = ("hu")
        
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        guard editingStyle == .delete else { return }
        pizzas.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        
    }
    
    
    func tableView2(_ tableView2: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath2: IndexPath) {
        guard editingStyle == .delete else { return }
        drinks.remove(at: indexPath2.row)
        //
        tableView2.deleteRows(at: [indexPath2], with: .automatic)
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        
        //        tableView1.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "CountryCell")
        
        tableView2.dataSource = self
        tableView2.delegate = self
                    tableView2.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "item2")
        
    }
    
    
    
    
    
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misunderstand how to implement the data source methods for 2 different table views.

Having 2 functions with different names as data source methods will not work:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int 

func tableView2(_ tableView2: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
```

That second function will never get called.

Your first function will be called for both table views. (The `tableView` parameter will tell you which one you are being asked about.) You need to have a switch statement that checks which table view you are being asked about:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int  {
switch tableView { //Switch on the parameter passed to the function
    case self.tableView:  //If we're being asked about our first tableView
        return pizzas.count
    case self.tableView2:  //If we're being asked about our 2nd tableView
        return drinks.count
    default: 
        return 0 //Should never happen
}
```

You'll need to apply the same logic to all of your data source and table view delegate methods.

Also, I would advise against using the name "tableView" for your table view instance variables. Having an instance variable name be the same as the parameter name passed in for your data source methods is confusing and asking for trouble. (Inside the data source methods, `tableView` refers to the table view that's passed in as a parameter, and `self.tableView` refers to the instance variable `tableView`. Instead I would suggest naming your table views something like `pizzasTableView` and `drinksTableView`.

Note that it might be easier to have a parent view controller with 2 child table view controllers. Each of those child view controllers can manage their own data source, and that way your data source code is cleaner and simpler.

Comment: I actually tried the way you're describing to begin with but I kept getting "unable to dequeue a cell with identifier item" (and getting it again now), so I tried the other way but I see your point - thanks for the details, I think I understand now!  Then im probably doing something else wrong with the dequeue.

Comment: Yeah, you will also need to have separate cell identifiers for each table view and have your switch statement return a cell dequeued with the correct identifier based on the table view that is specified.

Comment: of course! works perfectly! Thanks for your time! (and im definitely changing all the names to something more proper - Ive learned the hard way!

Comment: You should accept one of the answers given if they solved your problem

Answer (score 2):

This is not how `tableView's` `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` methods work.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {


func tableView2(_ tableView2: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
```

Writing 2 methods for `numberOfRowsInSection` is not correct. The 2nd one is not a `UITableViewDataSource` method and so it will never get called.

You need to create just one method and then check for the instance of `tableView` and `tableView2` inside it and then code accordingly..

**For example:**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if tableView == self.tableView {
        return pizzas.count
    } else {
        return drinks.count
    }
}
```

And this goes for all the UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate methods.

Answer (score 0):

assign tag values to your tableViews and register correct cells

```
func viewDidLoad() {
    tableView.tag = 1
    tableView2.tag = 2

    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self

    tableView2.dataSource = self
    tableView2.delegate = self
    
    //Register "itemTableViewCell" instead of UITableViewCell
    tableView2.register(itemTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "item2")
}
```

in your delegates, check which table view requests the data

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if tableView.tag == 1 {
        return pizzas.count
    } else if tableView.tag == 2 {
        return drinks.count
    }
 
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if tableView.tag == 1 {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "item", for: indexPath)
        return cell
    } else if tableView.tag == 2 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "item2", for: indexPath)
        return cell
    }
 }

//and so on..
```

Comment: Tags are a fragile way to keep track of multiple views on a form, and should be a last resort. See my and PGDev's answers for a better way.